# Create a trigger when updated value is 0

Tags: sql-server

I want to add for example 30 units when the field s_QuantidadeStock(Quantity in stock) reaches 0.
How to I do that using the trigger functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trUpdateQuantityInStock
on tblQuantittyInStock
after UPDATE
AS
begin
;with cte as ( --wrap query into CTE
select id, QInStock from inserted --new rows is here
where QInStock <= 0 -- your condition
)
update trUpdateQuantityInStock
set QInStock = 30
from trUpdateQuantityInStock t --update only rows
inner join cte on t.id = cte.id --where condition meets
end
```

### Explanations:

Full description is available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx
In nutshell, DML queries such as insert, update and delete create virtual tables `inserted` and `deleted` which are available in triggers (only). The schema of this tables match the schema of the table on which the trigger created (trUpdateQuantityInStock in this case).

Comment: Explanation, please!

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might work for you

```
    CREATE TRIGGER trUpdateQuantityInStock
    For UPDATE
    on tblQuantittyInStock
    AS
    BEGIN
      Declare @qty int
   set @qty=(select itemInStock From tblQuantittyInStock)
If @qty=0
Begin 
    UPDATE tblQuantittyInStock set QInStock=30
End
Else
Print 'Item is stock is not 0'

    END
```

Comment: 1) `from inserted` to work with newer data. 2) common error. What if you update several rows?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to implement the code.
Can you explain me what you did there? 
I "kinda" understand but not fully as I would like too

Comment: what you didn't understand Ricardo